# Error on install Pygame(3.9) install (Win10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pygame

Good morning, I have a hellish problem, recently I learned to learn python so I still don't know all the details of it, for an application I need to install pygame, however it doesn't matter what I do it always with the error in the installation (I was first using pycharm, but as it didn't work I tried to install directly on cmd)
error (CMD):

Collecting pygame
Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)

DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-w13ny5_t'
cwd: C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame
Complete output (17 lines):

```
WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...


Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
    buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
    deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
    and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
    reply = raw_input(
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

---

Error (Pycharm):

Collecting pygame
Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)

DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-bcdvahlg'
cwd: C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame
Complete output (17 lines):

```
WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...


Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
    buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
    deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
    and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
    reply = raw_input(
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 1):

To install pygame on Windows in PyCharm:

1. Go to the Terminal tab near to bottom of the screen in [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/)
2. `pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev14`